# Epitope annotated protein

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, immunology

What is epitope annotted protein?? 
 The book from which I got this term is : 
http://www.springer.com/biomed/immunology/book/978-1-4939-1114-1

Comment: Have a read through the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitope). BTW, you could have gotten that by googling "epitope".

Comment: so basically epitope and epitope annotted protein means epitope??

Comment: Yes, they're the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when asking about a specific small term, it's best to check your spelling.  If you actually look at the sentience, you will note that you left out a very important hyphen:

> Pellequer compared several propensity scale methods using a dataset of
>   14 **epitope-annotated proteins**. [emphasis added]

The phrase means that the protein sequences (amino acid sequence) has the [epitopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitope) marked on them.  If you look at the [cited paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/007668799103010E), you will see the various tables and break downs of determined epitopes.  Pellequer's group did a lot of the early work when people were still working on techniques to "map" out the locations of epitopes (which are often not in linear segments of the protein sequence due to the protein structure).